# About the absolute convergence of a series of measurable functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

Let $(X,\mathfrak M,\mu)$ be a measure space and $f_n:X\rightarrow [-\infty,+\infty]$ a measurable function for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Suppose that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\int_X\left|f_n\right|\,d\mu\right)<+\infty$$
and consider the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|f_n\right|\;,$$
By the monotone convergence theorem we know that:
$$\int_X\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|f_n\right|\,d\mu=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\int_X\left|f_n\right|\,d\mu\right)<+\infty$$
Now can I conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|f_n\right(x)|<+\infty$ for all $x\in X$?

I think that this condition is true only almost everywhere in $X$, because if the series attains infinite value on a set $E$ of measure $0$, then the integral on $E$ is $0$ (we have fixed the convention that $0\cdot\infty=0$).

Answer (score 3):

You can conclude the claim for almost all $x$ because the function $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lvert f_n \rvert $$ is integrable. However, the Lebesgue integral doesn't really care what happens on a set of measure $0$, so you can't up that to finiteness everywhere in $X$.